# How to align the buttons to be side by side?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to align the buttons to be side by side with a small space in between to tell them apart. There is a file input before the buttons in the same div because the different method being used.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <h1>Upload the file</h1>
      <hr>

      <form action="/upload-file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Select file</label>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="Dataset" id="Dataset">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="Dataset">Select file...</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">De-indentify</button>
      </form>
      
      <form action="/execute-file" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download it</button>
      </form>
      

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want `fileinput, button and button` ?

Comment: use display: inline or flex to handle the alignment issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the element where the buttons are in.

**For Example**:

```
 div {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 23%;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```

Something like that, or check this article out for a better explanation with an [example](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-align-divs-side-by-side.html).

Answer (score 0):

Floating the elements will cause issues with the elements afterwards to be aligned weirdly and causes headaches when trying to fix it.

I found that adding a CSS element of `display: block` on your buttons fixes the bootstrap buttons so that they end up side by side like you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you can do it with bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/ and below is simple example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">De-</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">it</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 form {
    display: inline;
  }
  .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Upload the file</h1>
        <hr>
        <form action="/upload-file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="Dataset">Select file...</label>
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="Dataset" id="Dataset">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">De-indentify</button>
        </form>
        <form action="/upload-file" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download it</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: you just need to add above css.